# microsoft.office.interop.word replace table text inside shape

Tags: c#, replace, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I'm using microsoft.office.interop.word to replace( table cells text )  and I'm keeping this table inside shape, I'm trying to replace the text  which is inside this table
but the Problem when  replacing  is done  the Table  Format  is  removing and rows is merging  like photo below. Please I need to fix my code somehow to keep formatting after replacing text

original doc
[image]

output doc
[image]

I'm using this code:

```
    private void FindAndReplace(Word.Application wordApp, object ToFindText, object replaceWithText)
    {

        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllforms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;
        int x = 0;
        var shapes = myWordDoc.Shapes;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in shapes)
        {
            if (shape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
            {
                var initialText = shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                var resultingText = initialText.Replace(ToFindText.ToString(), replaceWithText.ToString());
                if (initialText != resultingText)
                {
                    shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
                }
            }
        }
        wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText,
           ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
           ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
           ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
           ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
           ref replace, ref matchKashida,
           ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
           ref matchControl);
    }
    private void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object SaveAs)
    {
        try
        {

            Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
            object missing = Missing.Value;
            if (File.Exists((string)filename))
            {
                object readOnly = false;
                object isVisible = false;
                wordApp.Visible = false;
                myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                myWordDoc.Activate();

                wordApp.Application.Documents.Open(filename, ReadOnly: true, Visible: false);


                DataTable dtfees = DB.GetData("select fees from fees where feesid='" + 1 + "'");
                if (dtfees.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    string fees1 = dtfees.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    string fees2 = dtfees.Rows[1][0].ToString();
                    string fees3 = dtfees.Rows[2][0].ToString();
                    string fees4 = dtfees.Rows[3][0].ToString();
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "tyfes1", fees1);
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "Tyfes2", fees2);
                    this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "Tyfes3", fees3);


                }
                myWordDoc.SaveAs2(ref SaveAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                  ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                myWordDoc.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }


    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for answer back , please take another  look i put full code with more description

Comment: You misunderstood what [mcve] means. You added irrelevant stuff. Relevant information would be the word document used, the text meant to be inserted and the desired look after inserting that text

Comment: i wish this edit is useful

Comment: Consider giving your variables types other than `object`, and passing arguments by value instead of by reference. There is no need to pass, e.g., `matchCase` by reference; `Execute` is not going to change the value, and the code posted here does not check if it does in any case.

Comment: In Word you can use the VBA macro recorder which allows recording steps made manually and then generate a VBA macro which allows automating Word. So, following that way you may find properties and methods required for getting the job done. See [Create or run a macro](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing wrong with your code is that whatever material (text/tables etc.) is in your shape, if the findText is in it and the replacement text is different from the find text, the entire content of the shape's TexTObject will be replaced by a string with no table, in this line

```
shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = resultingText;
```

Judging from the Find.Execute that's still in your code, I'm guessing that you tried to use the Find object to do the replace but couldn't work out how to get it to work just in the Shapes.

If I have understood what you're doing, I think the following fairly simple change will work, but you will need to check the C# and test it.

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape shape in shapes)
        {
            if (shape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
            {
                shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find.Execute(ref ToFindText,
                    ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                    ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                    ref nmatchAllforms, ref forward,
                    ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                    ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                    ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                    ref matchControl);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thx a lot the code working fine now just need to Change                 shape.TextFrame.Find.Execute To shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Find.Execute

Comment: thx a lot it was so kind of you to help